# Best feature matcher for iris pictures

Tags: java, opencv, matching, iris-recognition

I want to write some code to perform an iris recognition. I've already had a iris pictures which is normalized to cartesian coordinates. I've try to match theese pics using Gabor filter and Hamming distance, but without a success.

So now I'm wondering if in openCV exists a matcher which will be good to provide this kind of recognition? I know there is some predefined matchers, but which one will be the best for very similar pictures? 
Let me also add that my application should decide if given iris exist already in database or not.

I'm using Java version of openCV

Comment: can you be a bit more explicit about the pipeline you used there ? using gabor features makes a lot of sense, but the hamming distance does not (unless you omit something)

Comment: @berak, I detect iris in eye image, cut it, transform to rectangular form. Next I use getGaborKernel function and convolute it with my iris image and put in db. I took next image do the same things and compute Hamming distance between input image and images in db.
Thanks for response however my question is a little bit different. If any of matchers in openCV manage my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Feature extraction & matching to the help!**

The problem is a typical recognition application. Inder to match two image successfully, you have to find some distinct or unique properties that will help you to find what you are looking for. These are called "Features" in pattern recognition/image processing environments. However, that is not simple as it is. There are many feature extraction methods which are already implemented in OpenCV **(SIFT, SURF, ORB** etc.)

[image: SIFT Features of Iris]

In Iris recognition case, you will need scale, illuminance and rotation invarient features. SIFT features will be the best candidate for this work.
Therefore, extract SIFT features of iris images and store them to the database. OpenCV also has feature matchers, **flaNN** is one of them.

[image: SIFT Matching]

**OpeCV**
*SIFT:*
http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html#gsc.tab=0
*FLANN:* http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html

Comment: That is the answer I expected, thank you. Unfortunatelly, the question was asked more than year ago and I have to end my work sooner. However, thanks so much :) Maybe some day I will try your hints